# Discrimination between set of binary distributions

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Suppose we know two sets of distributions
$A=\{p_1,p_2,\cdots,p_k\}$ and $B=\{q_1,q_2,\cdots,q_k\}$.
We are given $C=\{r_1,r_2,\cdots,r_k\}$ such that $r_i=p_i$ for all $i$ or $r_i=q_i$ for all $i$.

We can choose any $1\leq i \leq k$, and get a sample of $r_i$.
The goal is to determine which case it is with high probability, says $2/3$ use as few queries as possible.

It seems one can choose $j=\arg \max_i |p_i-q_i|$, and sample $r_i$ many times with $|p_i-q_i|$ denotes the total variance.

Is the number of queries $\Theta(1/\epsilon^2)$ with $\epsilon=|p_j-q_j|$

Answer (score 3):

One quick remark: the upper bound will be
$$
O\left(\min_j \frac{1}{H^2(p_j,q_j)}\right)
$$
where $H$ is the Hellinger distance, not TV (we have $H^2\lesssim TV \lesssim H$). The sample complexity of simple hypothesis testing is captured by Hellinger, not total variation.

I suspect this is tight on an instance-per-instance basis as well, but don't have a proof. Rather, I don't have a proof for adaptive algorithms (those which can choose which $i$ to query, based on previously received samples): for *non-adaptive* algorithms (which choose ahead of time how many samples to ask from each $i$), then I believe I can prove the lower bound, using elementary properties of Hellinger distance.

Comment: Incidentally, the above does not require anything about the distributions being "binary")

Comment: Thank you very much! May I have a reference for the upper bound?

Comment: @gondolf I don't have a simple reference, so I'll be lazy and point to this note I wrote myself: https://github.com/ccanonne/probabilitydistributiontoolbox/blob/master/testing.pdf (pdf)

Comment: Thanks! That is very nice.